# How to save data to an array object in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my mongoose schema model

```
userOrderedDetails: [
    {
        userOrderedId: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
         userOrderedEmail: {
        type: String,
        required: true
         }
    }
]
```

I use this to save my userOrderedId, and userOrderedEmail and it works but I get an empty array in my mongo database. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

```
const order= new Order ({
        userOrderDetailed: [{
            userOrderedId: "TestId", 
            userOrderedEmail: "TestEmail"
        }]
})
order.save()
```

My mongoDb result:

```
"userOrderedDetails": []
```

Update: I made a typo userOrderDetailed should be userOrderedDetails. Thanks to Neil! Problem solved now.

Comment: What do you mean "I get an empty array". As a response when doing the save?

Comment: just update my question

Comment: `"TestId"` is not an `ObjectId`. This will fail validation and tell you so. You are also missing brackets in the code, so this is clearly not your code. If you want help and you don't know what you are doing, you actually need to "show" people what you are "really" doing.

Comment: I cut it short to make thing easier for ppl to take a quick look and it is my code.

Comment: Well you cut out the important parts didn't you. Now you know not to do that. **"TestId" is not an ObjectId. This will fail validation and tell you so.** Now you know not to respond with trivial comments and read the obvious mistakes being pointed out to you. There will be a VERY LOUD error produced by this code. Therefore either A. You are not actually sending `"TestId"` but another real value that actually validates. B You still are not telling us everything because you simply could not possibly miss that error in the console.

Comment: @bork Read the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50017677/revisions) None of this is any real code. If it's "real code" then it would simply be given in context. Given the edit the content likely actually is `ObjectId` in the schema

Comment: Also `userOrderDetailed !== userOrderedDetails`

Comment: @Neil yes. Thank you for pointing userOrderDetailed ! == userOrderedDetails. I made a typo and I just correct the name and I got my data in my database now. I wish I could except your answer but i don't have the option

Comment: It's a typo. It's not really useful to others as a solution.